# why would such code cause duplicate form submitting?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to use ajax to submit my form and here is my php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("button#submitButton").click(function(e){
                    var frm = $("#testForm");
                    frm.submit(function(ev){
                        var smt = $("#submitButton");
                        $.ajax({
                            type : frm.attr('method'),
                            url : frm.attr('action'),
                            data : frm.serialize(),
                            success : function(d){
                                alert(d);
                            }
                        });
                        ev.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='testForm' action='process.php' method = 'post'>
            <label for='test1'>test1</label>
            <input name='test1' id='test1'></input>
            <button id='submitButton'>submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I clicked the button for the first time, it worked well, expected messages were alerted, however, if I click the button again, the message would be alerted twice, and if I click the button a third time, message would be alerted three times. Why would it behaves so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case every time the button is clicked a new form submit handler is added to the form, so when the button is clicked for the second time there are 2 submit handlers added to the form so the ajax code is executed 2 times, on next click there are 3 handlers registered so the ajax will executed 3 times.

Since the button is in the form, clicking it will trigger the form submit by default so you can directly register a form submit handler.

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $("#testForm");
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        var smt = $("#submitButton");
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (d) {
                alert(d);
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```